# How do I continue my try/catch in my while-loop

Tags: python, try-catch

I'm making this blackjack game and I'm sure if you've played the game you know the rules. Basically I have 5 amount of chips and I'm letting the user type in their bets for the round. I have this try catch block thats supposed to not let the user type in anything below 0 and above the `chip_amount`. My exception for `ValueError` works fine and the while-loop continues if the user types "fff" or anything thats not a number. The program exits after if the user types in anything under 0 and above `chip_amount`, this is because the while-loop stops and I can't put `continue` in my if test, how can I solve this in a good way?

```
print("\n==== BLACKJACK GAME ====")

print(f'\nYou have currently have {chip_amount} chips available.')

while True:
    try:
        chips_input = int(input("How many chips do you want to bet? "))
        if chips_input < 1:
            raise Exception("Sorry, you have to enter a number bigger than 1.")
        if chips_input > chip_amount:
            raise Exception(f'Sorry, you have to enter a number less than {chip_amount}.')
    except ValueError:
        print("\nYou have to enter a number!")
        continue
    else:
        print(f'\nYou bet {chips_input} chips out of your total of {chip_amount} chips.')

        print(f'\nThe cards have been dealt. You have a {" and a ".join(player_hand)}, with a total value of {player_total}.')
        print(f'The dealers visible card is a {dealer_hand[0]}, with a value of {dealer_total_sliced}.')
```

Comment: The `Exception` will break the while loop. Why not just replace it with a `print` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raise ValueErrors so that your except block will catch these too:

```
if chips_input < 1:
    raise ValueError("Sorry, you have to enter a number bigger than 1.")
if chips_input > chip_amount:
    raise ValueError(f'Sorry, you have to enter a number less than {chip_amount}.')
```

Comment: I see, this works. Only thing is that I can't have use the error message I've written in my if test, is there a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't follow. Can you edit your question to also include your unit test?

Comment: This is the current output. Lets say I type in 0, it immediately jumps to the exception

You have currently have 5 chips available.
How many chips do you want to bet? 0

You have to enter a number!
How many chips do you want to bet?

Comment: Either throw a different Error and add an extra except block to catch it for a different message, or just change your current except message to be something more general like "Invalid input, please try again"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an infinite `while True` loop, you can loop while the reply is valid

```
chip_amount = 10

print("\n==== BLACKJACK GAME ====")
print(f'\nYou have currently have {chip_amount} chips available.')
chips_input = input("How many chips do you want to bet? ")

while not chips_input.isdigit() or not chip_amount >= int(chips_input) >= 0:
    print(f"False entry, enter a number between 0 and {chip_amount}")
    chips_input = input("How many chips do you want to bet? ")

print(f'\nYou bet {chips_input} chips out of your total of {chip_amount} chips.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you say "while loop stops" you mean program exits with an `Exception`. This is because you are only excepting `ValueError` exceptions, but you raise an `Exception`, so it isn't caught and the error terminates the program.

It is bad practice to use the general `Exception` anyway. You should use pick a concrete `Exception` from https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

You could probably go with `ValueError` and catch them with the current `except` block you have